# AWS EMR Airflow: Postgresql Connector

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, airflow, amazon-emr

I'm launching AWS EMR jobs via Airflow which rely on saving the data onto a PostgreSQL database. Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, the connector is not available by default in EMR hence the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_emr_script.py", line 725, in <module>
    main()
  File "my_emr_script.py", line 718, in main
    .mode("overwrite") \
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1634133413183_0001/container_1634133413183_0001_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 1107, in save
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1634133413183_0001/container_1634133413183_0001_01_000001/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1634133413183_0001/container_1634133413183_0001_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1634133413183_0001/container_1634133413183_0001_01_000001/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1493.save.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverRegistry$.register(DriverRegistry.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.$anonfun$driverClass$1(JDBCOptions.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.$anonfun$driverClass$1$adapted(JDBCOptions.scala:102)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcOptionsInWrite.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcOptionsInWrite.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:221)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withTracker(SQLExecution.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.executeQuery$1(SQLExecution.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withTracker(SQLExecution.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:301)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

How can I ensure that when EMR starts it contains the PostgreSQL connector? I searched for ways to do it via bootstrapping but I failed to find an answer; all the official d[ocuments refer only the Presto version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/presto-adding-db-connectors.html).

Edit:

I followed @Emerson's suggestion and downloaded the .JAR onto an S3 folder and passed it via configs directly in Airflow JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES:

```
"Configurations": [
        {
            "Classification": "spark-defaults",
            "Properties":
                {
                    "spark.jar": "s3://{{ var.value.s3_folder }}/scripts/postgresql-42.2.5.jar",
                },
        }
    ],
```

In Airflow:

```
instance_type: str = 'm5.xlarge'


SPARK_STEPS = [
    {
        'Name': 'emr_test',
        'ActionOnFailure': 'CANCEL_AND_WAIT',
        'HadoopJarStep': {
            'Jar': 'command-runner.jar',
            "Args": [
                'spark-submit',
                '--deploy-mode',
                'cluster',
                '--master',
                'yarn',
                "s3://{{ var.value.s3_folder }}/scripts/el_emr.py",
                '--execution_date',
                '{{ ds }}'
            ],
        },
    }
]


JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES = {
    'Name': 'EMR Test',
    "ReleaseLabel": "emr-6.4.0",
    "Applications": [{"Name": "Hadoop"}, {"Name": "Spark"}],
    'Instances': {
        'InstanceGroups': [
            {
                'Name': 'Master node',
                'Market': 'SPOT',
                'InstanceRole': 'MASTER',
                'InstanceType': instance_type,
                'InstanceCount': 1,
            },
            {
                "Name": "Core",
                "Market": "SPOT",
                "InstanceRole": "CORE",
                "InstanceType": instance_type,
                "InstanceCount": 1,
            },
        ],
        'KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps': False,
        'TerminationProtected': False,
    },
    'Steps': SPARK_STEPS,
    'JobFlowRole': 'EMR_EC2_DefaultRole',
    'ServiceRole': 'EMR_DefaultRole',
    'BootstrapActions': [
        {
            'Name': 'string',
            'ScriptBootstrapAction': {
                'Path': 's3://{{ var.value.s3_folder  }}/scripts/emr_bootstrap.sh',
            }
        },
    ],
    'LogUri': 's3://{{ var.value.s3_folder }}/logs',
     "Configurations": [
        {
            "Classification": "spark-defaults",
            "Properties":
                {
                    "spark.jar": "s3://{{ var.value.s3_path }}/scripts/postgresql-42.2.5.jar"
                },
        }
    ]
}


emr_creator = EmrCreateJobFlowOperator(
        task_id='create_emr',
        job_flow_overrides=JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES,
        aws_conn_id='aws_conn',
        emr_conn_id='emr_conn',
        region_name='us-west-2',
    )
```

Unfortunately, the problem remains.

In addition, I tried modifying the bootstrap to download the .JAR:

```
cd $HOME && wget https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.2.5.jar
```

And pass that onto the configuration:

```
"Configurations": [
        {
            "Classification": "spark-defaults",
            "Properties":
                {
                    "spark.executor.extraClassPath": "org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.5",
                    "spark.driver.extraClassPath": "$HOME/postgresql-42.2.5.jar",
                },
        }
    ],
```

In airflow:

```
instance_type: str = 'm5.xlarge'
    
    
    SPARK_STEPS = [
        {
            'Name': 'emr_test',
            'ActionOnFailure': 'CANCEL_AND_WAIT',
            'HadoopJarStep': {
                'Jar': 'command-runner.jar',
                "Args": [
                    'spark-submit',
                    '--deploy-mode',
                    'cluster',
                    '--master',
                    'yarn',
                    "s3://{{ var.value.s3_folder }}/scripts/emr.py",
                    '--execution_date',
                    '{{ ds }}'
                ],
            },
        }
    ]
    
    
    JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES = {
        'Name': 'EMR Test',
        "ReleaseLabel": "emr-6.4.0",
        "Applications": [{"Name": "Hadoop"}, {"Name": "Spark"}],
        'Instances': {
            'InstanceGroups': [
                {
                    'Name': 'Master node',
                    'Market': 'SPOT',
                    'InstanceRole': 'MASTER',
                    'InstanceType': instance_type,
                    'InstanceCount': 1,
                },
                {
                    "Name": "Core",
                    "Market": "SPOT",
                    "InstanceRole": "CORE",
                    "InstanceType": instance_type,
                    "InstanceCount": 1,
                },
            ],
            'KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps': False,
            'TerminationProtected': False,
        },
        'Steps': SPARK_STEPS,
        'JobFlowRole': 'EMR_EC2_DefaultRole',
        'ServiceRole': 'EMR_DefaultRole',
        'BootstrapActions': [
            {
                'Name': 'string',
                'ScriptBootstrapAction': {
                    'Path': 's3://{{ var.value.s3_folder  }}/scripts/emr_bootstrap.sh',
                }
            },
        ],
        'LogUri': 's3://{{ var.value.s3_folder }}/logs',
         "Configurations": [
            {
                "Classification": "spark-defaults",
                "Properties":
                    {
                        "spark.executor.extraClassPath": "org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.5",
                        "spark.driver.extraClassPath": "$HOME/postgresql-42.2.5.jar",
                    },
            }
        ]
    }
    
    
    emr_creator = EmrCreateJobFlowOperator(
            task_id='create_emr',
            job_flow_overrides=JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES,
            aws_conn_id='aws_conn',
            emr_conn_id='emr_conn',
            region_name='us-west-2',
        )
```

This in turn, results in a new error which somehow makes Spark not able to read the JSON files, treating them as corrupt files.

```
root
 |-- _corrupt_record: string (nullable = true)
```

Lastly, the common `emr_boostrap.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash -xe

sudo pip3 install -U \
    boto3 \
    typing


cd $HOME && wget https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.2.5.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure how the emr is being provisioned but below is how you would do it.

First upload the postgres jdbc jar to an s3 location. THen refer to that when you provision the cluster.

If you are provisioning via Cloudformation then below is what you will need to do

```
  EMR:
    Type: AWS::EMR::Cluster
    Properties:
      Applications:
        - Name: Spark
      Configurations:
        - Classification: spark-defaults
          ConfigurationProperties:
            spark.jars: s3://path_to_jar/postgresql-42.2.11.jar
```

If its cli commands, then it would be something like below

```
aws emr create-cluster ...... --configurations config.json
```

where config.json may look like below

```
[
  {
    "Classification": "spark-defaults",
    "Properties": {
      "spark.jars": "s3://path_to_jar/postgresql-42.2.11.jar"
     }
  }
]
```

EDIT:

After seeing ur edited question  , I can see ur spark submit args( SPARKSTEP variable).
In that section just add two more items like below

```
‘—jars’
‘s3://pathtodriver/postgresdriver.jar’
```

Comment: Hi @Emerson, thank you for your reply! Unfortunately, I tried following your steps but the problem remains. I edited my original answer to reflect your suggestions and other things I tried.

Comment: If I are using the airflow operators then u can just pass the — jars flag with the s3 path of the jdbc driver as part of your arguments. It would really help if u put in ur description how u are provisioning the cluster or how I are running the job

Comment: Would be good to see how your are doing your spark submit. It is possible to pass the jars when u do the spark-submit

Comment: Hi @Emerson, you are right, I apologize I should have included everything. I updated my response! As for the passing the jars in spark-submit, is it via the "--packages" flag?

Comment: Nope. It’s —jars.  Adding ur jdbc driver there will work

Comment: Solved ! Thank you @Emerson!

Comment: does that mean the `config.json` does not need the `spark.jars` config -- seems like that would be redundant.

Comment: It’s not actually. If u specify it in the confit against the spark.jars property then u don’t need to specify the jars flag when u do a spark submit. If u look at the question above , u can see that the wrong property was set , hence the reason it didn’t work